# How to use bitwise operators to isolate bits from unsigned ints in C?

Tags: c, bit-manipulation, bit

this seems to be working well for me except this one time. I'm trying to get the first 10 bits of this number

```
unsigned char c= 17512807u<<22>>22;
```

I expect this to be 359 or 0101100111 but I'm getting 103 or 0001100111. Is there a reason that this is happening?

Comment: An unsigned character is 8 bits, so it can only contain values between 0 and 255. The value of 359 you want cannot fit in an unsigned char.

Comment: `0101100111` is 10 bits. `unsigned char` is 8 (probably).

Comment: Assuming ints are 32-bits in your machine, this should give you the low-order 10 bits, not the high-order ("first") 10 bits.  The result will be truncated to 8 bits when stored in `c` (assuming 8-bit characters).

Comment: Notem it is not bad to put `u` in `17512807u`, but it is not needed.

Answer (score 1):

The result you are getting is correct due to the truncation to 8-bit `unsigned char` value (when assigning to `c`).

If you need a value that is 10-bits wide you should use a different datatype, like `uint16_t` or an `unsigned int`.

[Reference to C++ integer datatypes](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/types/integer)